# Подсчёт символов на Си

Tags: c

Как то не так работает код( - не выводится `nc` в консоли

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём проблема ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF) 
        ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

Как я понимаю - код не выходит из цикла `while`, иначе бы всё было ровно.

- Но вроде книга пытается научить меня подсчитывать символы и в тоже время, приведённый там код не выходит из цикла - постоянно запрашивая ввод...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565663/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOF будет, когда вы нажмете Ctrl-Z в Windows, Ctrl-D в Linux - словом, закроете входной поток.

Или при перенаправлении потока из файла, типа

```
prog.exe < ll
```

в командной строке - тут вы получите количество символов в файле.

Comment: я должен нажать Ctrl-Z в консоли ? при нажатии в консоли, я получаю ^Z -  UPD: Разобрался